# Filter/Subset R dateframe based on other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two dataframes one with a corr matrix and one with the corresponding p-values (i.e. both are ordered, each position in each dataframe corresponds to the same variable). I would like to filter elements in the corr dataframe based on 2 conditions:

1) compare each column to the element in the first row of that column, elements smaller should become NA or 0.

2) if the corresponding element in the 2nd dataframe is larger than say 0.05, the element should again become 0.

An example would look like this:

```
set.seed(2)
a = sample(runif(5)  ,rep=TRUE) 
b = sample(runif(5)  ,rep=TRUE)
c = sample(runif(5)  ,rep=TRUE)
corr_mat = data.frame(a,b,c)       

a = sample(runif(5,0,0.1)  ,rep=TRUE) 
b = sample(runif(5,0,0.1)  ,rep=TRUE)
c = sample(runif(5,0,0.1)  ,rep=TRUE)
p_values= data.frame(a,b,c)
```

So I would like to subset corr_mat in a way that in column a only those value remain that are larger then the row 1 in column a AND the corresponding p-value in p_values is smaller than 0.05.

This is the output I would like to have for these values:

```
 > corr_mat
      a         b         c
 1 0.9438393 0.4052822 0.8368892
 2 0.1848823 0.4052822 0.6618988
 3 0.9438393 0.2388948 0.3875495
 4 0.5733263 0.7605133 0.3472722
 5 0.5733263 0.5526741 0.6618988

 > p_values
        a          b          c
 1 0.086886104 0.01632009 0.02754012
 2 0.051428176 0.09440418 0.09297202
 3 0.016464224 0.02970107 0.02754012
 4 0.086886104 0.01150841 0.09297202
 5 0.001041453 0.09440418 0.09297202
```

Target output (based on 1st condition, bigger than or equal to first row value for each column):

```
 > corr_mat
      a         b         c
 1 0.9438393 0.4052822 0.8368892
 2           0.4052822  
 3 0.9438393            
 4           0.7605133  
 5           0.5526741
```

Target output (based on both conditions- now excluding corresponding the p-values larger than 0.05):

```
 > corr_mat
      a         b         c
 1 0.9438393 0.4052822 0.8368892
 2             
 3 0.9438393            
 4           0.7605133  
 5
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
 apply(corr_mat_df,2, comp)
```

where comp is defined as something that compares row 1 of column a in corr_mat AND the corresponding element in p_values.

```
comp<-function(df1,df2) {
for (i in 1:length(df1)) {
if (df[i]<df[1] & df2[i]>0.05){
  df[i]=NA
}
}
}
```

Comment: The output for `corr_mat[1,1]` should be `NA` right? because `p_values[1, 1]` is 0.086886104 which is greater than 0.05 ?

Comment: hmm, actually I had  not thought about that. Both alternatives (NA and not NA even if p_val us bigger than 0.05) make sense for my analysis actually and I am able to change it now myself if need be with the solution you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to apply both the conditions in one go using `replace`. We `replace` the values which satisfies one of the condition with `NA`.

```
mapply(function(x, y) replace(x, (x < x[1]) | (y > 0.05), NA),corr_mat, p_values)


#             a         b         c
#[1,]        NA 0.4052822 0.8368892
#[2,]        NA        NA        NA
#[3,] 0.9438393        NA        NA
#[4,]        NA 0.7605133        NA
#[5,]        NA        NA        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also do by

```
corr_mat *NA^(corr_mat < corr_mat[1,][col(corr_mat)] | p_values > 0.05 )
#         a         b         c
#1        NA 0.4052822 0.8368892
#2        NA        NA        NA
#3 0.9438393        NA        NA
#4        NA 0.7605133        NA
#5        NA        NA        NA
```

Or just assign

```
corr_mat[corr_mat < corr_mat[1,][col(corr_mat)] | p_values > 0.05] <- NA
```

Comment: Also very nice, thank you so much. I will add both approaches to my personal "cheat sheet", I am sure both will come in handy.